# Javascript understanding return

Tags: javascript

Why is the alert not working if I erase namePosition? Is Javascript read line by line(top to bottom) when executed? If yes then the alert should work because it is executed/read first before the return.

```
function positionIdentifier(name, nameArray) {
  var namePosition;
  for (i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    if (nameArray[i] == name) {
      namePosition = function() {
        alert("Your name is in position number " + (i + 1));
      }
      return namePosition;
    }

  }

}

name1Array = ["look", "sky", "walk", "kier"];
positionIdentifier("walk", name1Array)();
```

Comment: you're assigning namePosition to a function. you have to actually call that function to execute the code. if you return it, you call it.

Comment: All you've done is declare a function. It needs to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Your function runs as is, However, there is no need to declare/name the function that is going to be returned. Just return the function. This simplifies the code quite a bit. Also, you didn't declare your loop variable or your array variable with `var`, which would cause them to become global. Remember to declare all variables.

```js
function positionIdentifier(name,nameArray){
      
  for(var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++){
        if(nameArray[i] == name){
          return function(){
            alert("Your name is in position number "+(i+1));
          }
        }
  }
}

var name1Array = ["look","sky","walk","kier"];
positionIdentifier("walk", name1Array)();
```