# Javascript how return works

Tags: javascript

I actually want to update my previous question  [Javascript understanding return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475814/javascript-understanding-return) because the code below is quite similar to the previous one but since that question was answered already I decided to post this. The code of my previous questions works fine already but I want to satisfy some of my curiosities so I experimented the code and moved the return namePosition,

```
function positionIdentifier(name, nameArray) {
  var namePosition;
  for (i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    if (nameArray[i] == name) {
      namePosition = function() {
        alert("Your name is in position number " + (i + 1));
      }

    }

  }
return namePosition;

}

name1Array = ["look", "sky", "walk", "kier"];
positionIdentifier("walk", name1Array)();
```

Why does it alert the wrong position (i+1)? Instead it alerts the final position which is the length of the array.

Comment: Once the function you return gets executed, variable `i` will be the length of the array. Look up closures here, since this is a duplicate. Ps: the function you show here already exists: `name1Array.indexOf('walk') + 1`

Answer (score 0):

That my friend is what is called a closure in javascript.

```
function() {
  alert("Your name is in position number " + (i + 1));
}
```

When ***positionIdentifier*** function is invoked, ***i*** has the last value from the ***for*** loop.

To fix this you need to do this

```
function positionIdentifier(name, nameArray) {
  var namePosition;
  for (i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    if (nameArray[i] == name) {

      /*  now this will keep the correct value of i */
      namePosition = (function(i) {
          return function(){
              alert("Your name is in position number " + (i + 1));
          }
      })(i)
      /*  now this will keep the correct value of i */

    }
  }
  return namePosition;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uxyot51b/

Comment: all except one "i"s in the array don't satisfy the conditional "if", so the "i" in the alert should be preserved, why does it inherit the variable i in the for loop then? Closures are really confusing.

Comment: @MarkLemuelGenita:  closure are not confusing. think of them as this way. 
is there is a function within a function, the inner function remembers the environment in which it was created, and keeps the reference of the value of variables. so, when you execute, 
var innerFunc = positionIdentifier();
and then do innerFunc() --> this function remembers the value and because of execution the current value of I --> last value.
Hope this helps. Upvote if it solves your problem.

Comment: back to my original functions\, since I put the return namePosition outside the "for loop" block, does it mean that "execute this function after the for loop is done", so the i to be executed is the final i inside for loop?

Comment: Doesn't matter. even if you have return namePosition; within the for loop. You'll have same scenario. see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z7z94yyc/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use break statement here is correct code:

```
<script>
        function positionIdentifier(name, nameArray) {
            var namePosition;
            for (i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
                if (nameArray[i] == name) {
                    namePosition = function () {
                        alert("Your name is in position number " + (i + 1));
                    };
                    break;
                }

            }
            return namePosition;

        }

        name1Array = ["look", "sky", "walk", "kier"];
        positionIdentifier("walk", name1Array)();
    </script>
```

Comment: forget the break statement :), back to the original function all except one "i"s in the array don't satisfy the conditional "if", so the "i" in the alert should be preserved, why does it inherit the variable i in the for loop then? Closures are really confusing.